# Unable to compile Opencv 2.4.5 using cmake -G Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am getting an error message when compiling opencv 2.4.5 on Xcode 4.6

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Xcode ..
```

I get the following errors:

> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (message):
>
> CMake fails to deterimine the bitness of target platform.
>
> ```
> Please check your CMake and compiler installation. If you are crosscompiling
> ```
>
> then ensure that  your CMake toolchain file correctly sets the compiler details.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Any ideas?

Comment: why not just use homebrew ? brew install opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fabrizioM mentioned, you can use homebrew, or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org).

You can of course build from source as well.
With your setup, my guess is either Xcode command line tools aren't installed, or they are installed but not added to your path.

To install the command line tools, go to **Preferences (CMD+,)** then **Downloads** and install Command Line Tools from there.

To setup the path, edit either ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile and append to the PATH variable.
For example

```
nano ~/.profile
```

then in the file:

```
# xcodebuild (required to compile .xcodeproj files via CL)
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

After you're done, open a new Terminal tab and type xcodebuild to test.

The above should work at this point. After cmake generated xcode build
you can run `xcodebuild`.

Personally I prefer using ccmake.. to configure extra settings, fix missing dependencies,etc.:

```
cd opencv-2.4.5
mkdir build && cd build
ccmake ..
```

Then use 'c' to configure, 'g' to generate and finally:

```
make
make install
```

Which doesn't need Xcode and command line tools.

Comment: Hi George, you are right! I have Xcode command tools installed but they are not added to my path.